# INSERT ONLY SPECIFIC COLUMN FROM A STORED PROCEDURE RESULT

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I want to know if it is possible to insert to a table from a specific column of result from a stored procedure?

Something like:

```
declare @temp as table(
id int
)

insert @temp
exec getlistofStudents --returns multiple columns
```

this is an example only, Thanks for the help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SELECT \* INTO \[temp table\] FROM \[stored procedure\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: you can get all columns from stored proc not a single column..

Answer (score 1):

You can take a 2 step approach. First INSERT INTO a #TempTable, then populate the @TempVariable with another INSERT INTO, selecting the single column.

```
DECLARE @temp AS TABLE
(
   ID int
);

CREATE TABLE #tempTable1
(
   Column1 int,
   Column2 int   
);

INSERT INTO #tempTable1
Exec getlistofStudents

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT Column1 FROM #tempTable1
```